# Clear Cookies in Spring Boot WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, cookies, spring-webflux, servlet-3.0

I am trying to delete all cookies while i logout from my app. I am able to do it for Spring boot web project as below.

```
/**
     * Clears all the cookies from the response
     *
     * @param req
     * @param resp
     */
    public static void deleteCookies(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookieToBeDeleted : cookies) {
                logger.debug("Deleting cookie: {} having value: {}", cookieToBeDeleted.getName(),
                        cookieToBeDeleted.getValue());
                cookieToBeDeleted.setMaxAge(0);
                resp.addCookie(cookieToBeDeleted);
            }
        }
    }
```

But the same for webflux is tricky. Instead of HttpServletRequest we have org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest. And instead of cookie array we have a multimap here.

```
 private void deleteCookies(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        MultiValueMap<String, HttpCookie> cookies = request.getCookies();

        for (Entry<String, List<HttpCookie>> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
            log.debug(cookie.toString());
        }

        log.debug("Response cookies" + response.getCookies().toString());

    }
```

Can spring webflux experts help me to implement the logic here.

Answer (score 1):

Able to delete cookies for webflux.

```
/**
     * Clears all the cookies from the response
     *
     * @param request
     * @param response
     */
    public void deleteCookies(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        MultiValueMap<String, HttpCookie> cookies = request.getCookies();

        for (Entry<String, List<HttpCookie>> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
            for (HttpCookie cookieToBeDeleted : cookie.getValue()) {
                log.debug("Deleting cookie: {} having value: {}", cookieToBeDeleted.getName(), cookieToBeDeleted
                        .getValue());
                response.addCookie(ResponseCookie.from(cookieToBeDeleted.getName(), cookieToBeDeleted.getValue())
                        .maxAge(0).build());
            }
        }

        log.debug("Response cookies" + response.getCookies().toString());

    }
```